# Mapbox Web API - How to get the latitude and longitude of the search result?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am using *Mapbox* on my website. Everything is working fine but one thing that I am looking for is how can I get the *latitude* and *longitude* of the searched result/location in *Mapbox*?

I didn't find any related [event](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/) to achieve what I want nor [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/).

I am using *Mapbox* Web API Javascript. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can't say that I've used the API, but here's what I think:

```js
map.on('sourcedata', function(e){
  if(e.isSourceLoaded){
    console.log(e.coord);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried but sometimes it didn't work for me. This event sometimes not going to be called. I tried!!!!

Comment: And second thing is that `e.coords` is `undefined`.